# Android layout - listview and edittext view overlap

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

In my app I've got an activity with an EditText view on top of a ListView. The simple problem I'm having is that the topmost element of the list is "underneath" the EditText view.

I'm not very experienced in Android and so I have no idea how to fix this!

[image]

My xml looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".AcceptDeliveriesMainActivity"  >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- Editext for Search -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search_field_text"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- List View -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just put `</LinearLayout>` after ListView tag and replace orientation of `LinearLayout` to `verticle` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as long as your linearlayout just contains one element, so you can delete it.

you have to use `android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch"` in your listview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".AcceptDeliveriesMainActivity"  >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />


    <!-- List View -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### If you don't want to remove the linearlayout

you can use this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".AcceptDeliveriesMainActivity"  >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/llID"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- Editext for Search -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- List View -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llID" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the previous code, I just gave an ID to the linearlayout and made the listview below it

Answer (score 1):

You should replace your parent RelativeLayout with a LinearLayout.Or place the child views in relation to each other like android:layout_below which will then align children in relation to each other. Else each child will align to top left of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Tell your 2nd ListView to `layout:below` your LinearLayout.